# Xcode 6 Storyboard can't center

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard

I have an issue trying to center an object in a storyboard. I've created a new "Single-view Application" project, entered a main.Storyboard and I'm trying to add a label to center of it. On a preview of this storyboard for 4-inch iPhone, the label isn't centered, even when I force storyboard to use 3.5, 4, or 4.7-inch iPhones. Adding constraints makes no difference. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It could be possible, the constraints you've specified doesn't satisfy the requirements you are looking for.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you want to center the label vertically and horizontally, you can use Align option at the storyboard. On your storyboard's bottom right corner, there are four options and the first one is Align option, selecting it will give you to choose the alignment for your object as follows,

[image: Alignment option]

Here in the screenshot, you can see that I have selected two options if I want to center my  object in both dimension. You can choose either one of them or both based on your requirements and press **Add 2 constraints** button and it will work consistently for any sized screen. However make sure to select the object you want to center before selecting the **Align** option.

Comment: That's resolve the issue, thanks!
But i still can't understand, why all these drug and drop in center moves needs then =/

Answer (score 1):

Try using the reset to suggested constraints. It works quite well for simple layout. Otherwise, you just have to fine tune your constraints 
[image: reset to suggested constraints.]

Comment: How could it will help solving the problem as you are trying to reset to suggested constraints which will be based on what you've specified and the specified constraints couldn't be correct?

Comment: Suggested constraints are not based on what you set. The are auto computed based on the location of your outlet. [see](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/WorkingwithConstraints/WorkingwithConstraints.html)

Comment: But your outlet's position can be incorrectly positioned then your suggested constraints may not work properly,isn't it?

Comment: That's really another opportunity to do, what i wanted, so thanks! At least you can change constraints after reseting them, if something went not how you expected :)