# iOS Swift first app, controls dont appear

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I have created my first app with xcode and swift followin a tutorial.
I have added a button and 2 images to the main story board.

I have also added some easy code:

http://screencast.com/t/m8DVzHNNz60M[image]

However when I run the app, the simulator is blank, nothing in it, and the button I know its not hidden.

[image]

Comment: Did you set constraints for displaying your elements on screen? Look at the icons to the right of the blue bar below your storyboard. Especially the second and third one from right to left.

Comment: I dont remember I changed that: http://screencast.com/t/uxT9gTMPoH7z

Comment: You use constraints to place elements on your layout. Did you notice that the screen is a square and not an actual rectangular screen? That's intended. You're designing for any size. If you want to place, for instance, a label on top of the screen and it needs to use the whole width, you would define a top, left and right constraint, plus the height of the element. By a general rule, you need two horizontal (left, right) and two vertical (top and height) constraints to place an object correctly on screen.

Comment: Of course it could be any mixture. You could also define to center horizontally (third button from right to left) and a fixed width, then center vertically with a fixed height, or whatever fits your needs. You should see AutoLayout tutorials on YouTube, it's easier than it looks.

Comment: Another good resource that could help you understand this are the Stanford University videos on iTunes U. With the first 4 or 5 videos you'll get the basics to keep going.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few things that could be wrong.

**1.** Your button isn't centered. You need to center it using constraints. Check out this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26959256/5143847

**2.** In your `IBAction`, you are hiding your button. Try this:

```
uncoolButton.hidden = false
```

Or you can just remove it completely. Based on your question, it seems like you want to keep the button showing.

Comment: as newbie I was playing around and now I remember the only thin I moved, its this one, http://screencast.com/t/Z6Xe3y2a, I dont really understand it, but it looks like when I select another option all controls disappear, so I am not sure which one I should use.

Comment: @EstebanV You don't need to do that. For now, leave at 2x2 so it is simple.